# flash player plugin 11.2.202.442 over 11.2.202.440 update

Tags: 12.04, updates, firefox, flash

How do I install flash player 11.2.202.442 over 11.2.202.440?  Using Ubuntu 12.04.

This is my wife's computer, and she just told me she can't see any videos using Flash Player. Message says She needs to update...  I'm not sure about the "right" procedure.

I need step by step info (or tutorial), so that I can show her how it's done.

Comment: Could be that Firefox keep incorrect 'latest' flash version in `pluginreg.dat` file. You can try delete it from `~/.mozilla/firefox/some name.default/` (src [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/firefox))

Answer (score 0):

You can download and update it from **Adobe** website :

http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

or download **flash player 11.2.202.442**  debian package :

http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/canonical_partner/trusty/partner/base/adobe-flashplugin

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DavidFoerster You're right, i won't do it again :D.

Comment: Though in this case it's more about the missing instructions than the possibility of the links going offline. I guess Adobe only takes their Flash download page offline after they discontinue its support.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed as though Ubuntu 14.04 did not want to install the APT package from adobe with ubuntu software center. I uninstalled and installed/upgraded with synaptic and apt-get as well and got no joy.
I was able to:
sudo dpkg -i Downloads/adobe-flashplugin_11.2.202.442-0trusty1_i386.deb
with the .deb referenced here previously and go 'round the problem and flash is now playing in firefox again.